# How login is possible, if I deny login page via nginx?

Tags: login, security

I am running a simple up-to-date WP site. 
To change the WP Login URL I use AIO WP Security & Firewall plugin, it also inform me about wrong login attempts. 

I thought to make it harder to enter I add to the nginx config following entry:

```
   location /newlogin {
    allow 123.123.123.123;
    deny  all;
 }
```

`http://www.example.org/newlogin` is my WP Login defined in that AIO plugin. 
I can only access the WP site from that IP I allowed. 
**BUT** still I receive those login attmept email... 
How is that possible? How can somebody try the Login without executing that URL?

Answer (score -1):

They can use the following address: http://www.example.org/wp-admin